# How can I check if a HashSet contains an item using the hash of the item?

Tags: c#, hash, hashcode, hashset

I want to check if a HashSet contains a specific element. I already have the `int` hashcode of the element but not a reference to the element itself.

Is it possible to do this without iterating over the whole set?

Comment: Having the hashcode doesn't mean its the only object with that particular hashcode. That's why you need to override the GetHashcode() and Equals() methods, so that if two objects produce the same hashcode, the `Equals` method gets called. So in short, you won't be able to do it because you cannot implement the `Equals` method

Comment: It's a valid question imo though - if this functionality was support you would only have to search through the items in the same bucket (items that have the same hashcode)

Comment: @BrokenGlass Even then, how would you compare those items in that bucket to the `int` hashcode you have? There is no equality metric (at least the OP hasn't mention one that could be used)

Comment: You can't as Moop pointed out. What you are describing is something akin to a Bloom filter. With a hash code, all you can say about an item is "possibly in the set" or "definitely not in the set".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, because

- there is no one-to-one mapping of hash code to object ([pigeon principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle))
- .Net `HashSet` / `Dictionary` don't expose this implementaion details

If you really need to find object by hash code you can

- iterate all items and compare hash code
- if this is main functionality - consider if custom  comparer that will let you have special object that will match any other object with the same hash code will work...

Approximate code for special comparer

```
 class ObjectsToStore
 {
     ....
     public int? HashCodeOverwrite; 
 }

 class ComparerByHashCode : IEqualityComparer<ObjectsToStore>
 {

   public bool Equals(ObjectsToStore b1, ObjectsToStore b2)
   {
       if (b1.HashCodeOverwrite.HasValue || b2.HashCodeOverwrite.HasValue)
       {
           return b1.GetHashCode() == b2.GetHashCode());
       }
       // add all null checks here too.
       return b1.Equals(b2);
   }

   public int GetHashCode(ObjectsToStore b)
   {
     return b.HashCodeOverwrite.HasValue? b.HashCodeOverwrite.Value:b.GetHashCode();
   }
 }
```

Approximate usage:

```
var myHashSet = new HashSet<ObjectsToStore>(new ComparerByHashCode());
var itemByHashCode = myHashSet[new ObjectsToStore{HasCodeOverwrite= 1234}];
```

Answer (score 0):

No. Hash functions are one-way functions. It maps instances from a (potentially infinity large) space to a limited large space. It speeds up process, but doesn't guarantee uniqueness.

A very simply hash function in daily life can be: to store employee records, the secretary uses 26 folders, named 'A' to 'Z'. Juliet's record is stored in folder 'J', Mike's record in 'M', Charlie's in 'C'. Now I give you these 26 folders, and you want to know whether there is someone called Oscar in the company. Unless the 'O' folder is empty, you'll have to check every record in that folder to tell the answer.